# CSV converter Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csv

I am writing a handler in my spring boot application to convert object into CSV . If the user wants only header , only CSV header should be returned. there are two other options - header_and_body and body_only.

for some reason, header_only returns only empty file. Why is that ? I tried to add p.println() for the header_only option, still  only empty file is returned

The complete code is below: Well not complete , I kept getting this error in Stack Overflow " It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." So I removed few irrelevant  code for the topic under discussion.

```
public class CsvHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<CsvResponse> {


    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(CsvResponse response, HttpOutputMessage output)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        output.getHeaders().setContentType(MEDIA_TYPE);
        output.getHeaders().set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + response.getFilename() + "\"");
        OutputStream out = output.getBody();
        writeRecords(response, out, response.getOption());
        out.close();
    }

    private void writeRecords(CsvResponse response, OutputStream out, String option) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(out);
        List<DynamicMarketData> list = response.getRecords();
        String header = mdhTotemConfiguration.getColumnListForCommodities();
        if (option.equals("header_only") || option.equals("header_and_body"))
        {
            p.print(header);
        }
        if (option.equals("body_only") || option.equals("header_and_body"))
        {
            for (DynamicMarketData elem : list) {   
                p.println();
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = elem.getDynamicMarketData().entrySet().iterator();
                do {
                    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = entries.next();
                    p.print(entry.getValue());
                    if (entries.hasNext() == true)
                        p.print(",");
                } while (entries.hasNext());
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: No error message Harry

Comment: `p.flush(); p.close();` when done.

Comment: After p.print(header) correct? Thanks . Will try

Comment: [Some possible helpful reading](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/Java5/Notes/chap83/ch83_14.html).

Comment: When you are done writing everything (before your method exits).

Comment: Great. Thanks so much

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @DevilsHnd  This worked beautifully. Thanks again